# Navbar google style with JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile Navbar that I would like to style with css like the very top navigation menu on google.

Can someone please help me out with the styles?

Or at least tell me which styles I need to override and how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Inspect the element you want to style in your Developer Tools. It just doesn't get any easier than that.

Comment: @Jasper I can't understan which classes I need to "override" (if I need to override them) and how to do it :(

Comment: In your developer tools (any I've seen) when you inspect an element you can see it's CSS rules/styles. The style declarations are generally displayed just like they are in the style-sheet: `.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview { some-style: some-value; }`. You can either overwrite the styles by adding `!important` to your own declaration or you can make the CSS rules slightly more specific so they are used over the default theme.

Comment: If you need more help diagnosing jQuery Mobile specific CSS, then see my other answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A752738+%5Bcss%5D%5Bjquery-mobile%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just created something you could use. It's not perfect, but it looks very much like Google. (Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/dAUbu/)

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header" class="header-google">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Yay!</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.header-google {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: #2D2D2D;
}

.header-google a.ui-btn {
    border: none;
    background: inherit;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #BBB;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.header-google .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.header-google a.ui-btn.ui-btn-active,
.header-google a.ui-btn:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}
```